# Applying an if statement formula for the entire row in excel

Tags: excel

I have an if statement working properly in only one cell. `=IF(B28="Others",+C28, 0)`. However, I also want to include the cells `B28` to `B30` and will add `C28` to `C30` respectively in the formula. How will I be able to do so? I have tried this formula: `=IF(B28:B30="Others",+C28:C30, 0)` but it won't work.

What I want to happen is this:
I will input values in the cells `C28:C30`, and if they're under a certain category (ex. `B28` says 'Others'), that value will be added to that category above (ex. C18 for 'Others').

If it works, `C18` should have a value of `1,450` since `1,150` and `300` are both under 'Others'.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function you're looking for is `SUMIF()`. You can read about it [here](https://support.office.com/en-sg/article/SUMIF-function-169b8c99-c05c-4483-a712-1697a653039b).

The complete formula you need is: `=SUMIF(B28:B30,"Others",C28:C30)`

Comment: + for taking the time to include the support.office.com link.

Answer (score 0):

you might want to use a sumif statement where you're summing on the values in C based on the category in B

http://www.exceltrick.com/formulas_macros/excel-sumif-and-sumifs/

Comment: I don't know if that would be my first choice for an off-site reference on the [SUMIF function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIFS-function-c9e748f5-7ea7-455d-9406-611cebce642b).

Comment: it has more examples than the office support page - official documentation isn't always that useful

Comment: *'isn't always that useful '* is subjective. Either the support.microsoft.com page for SUMIF is useful or it is not. I think it is and fail to see how anyone could think it is not.

Comment: true, it is indeed subjective, which is why I looked at both and in my opinion made the subjective decision that the support.microsoft.com page was not the best resource in this case and chose a different one